# Stretch marks during weight training

Tags: weightlifting, injury, recovery, injury-prevention, push-ups

I am 15 and my height is 5 ft. 7. I started working out about two months ago. I only did tricep push ups, bicep curls, and skull crushers because I was warned that workouts will stunt my growth. I just bulked right away without cutting. When I reached two weeks of work outs, I had stretch marks on my shoulders and biceps. I first thought that it was a scar of honor but as time passed it grew larger and deeper. Right now, it is very visible when I wear tank tops or sleeveless shirts. I want to cure this, but if it is hard to do so, I want to know how to prevent it. 
Now I want to ask about the second part of this story. So, my father said that I am growing up and building mass at the same time, and by now my fragile skin cannot take it. He recommends me to workout when I am about 17, when I would already have strong skins that can endure such circumstances. Is this true? or do I just have to live with it. Lastly, this is not that important, but what would people think when they notice my stretch marks? Would they freak out or give me a disgusting look? 
People who have already gone through this process, I would be grateful if you help me out.

Comment: Remember, developing physique is a marathon, not a race. Also, focusing on isolation work like curls and tricep work only really engages a few arm-muscles. Look to compound movements: Overhead press, Bench, Squat, Deadlift, Row to develop muscle in a more balanced way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am 35 years old and started lifting weights when I was 13 years old. I also have stretch marks where my pecks (pectoral muscle) chest connects with the shoulder. Stretch marks are due to the elasticity of your skin. Skin can stretch a certain amount, but it's ability to stretch is highly affected by what you consume (eat). Sugar intake will make your skin very inflexible and not able to stretch. I recommend eating 14 to 28 grams or less of sugar a day if you want to have the most skin elasticity(stretchability). This will be the case if you are 13, 17 or 35 etc.

What people think of your stretch marks is irrelevant. If someone is judging you by your appearance then they have missed a great deal and are clueless. All bodies fade to dust and there is always someone stronger than you. I recommend working out to gain strength to use for the greater good of all humankind. Pick up someone who has a broken leg, lift a log off of a child, carry a heavy object for someone... etc. I started working out to defend myself from bullies at school and over the years I have grown quite a bit mentally and I realize that things here can be very confusing and only you personally will be able to figure this life out with contemplation and experience. One thing that is hard to learn is that a positive attitude has far more weight on attraction than just the physical body. A great attitude with a big smile is key, muscles won't get you there alone.

Others are correct lifting is a lifelong process and two months is nothing (I know you worked hard and I do not de-value any of your hard work). I highly suggest you workout every other day for the rest of your life... only skip when necessary or on rare occasion. It is this sort of consistent workout which will serve you well. Your body will acquire the ability to heal very quickly compared to non-lifters because of the constant micro-tearing and healing of your muscle tissue. This ability to heal is not isolated to just your muscles... your whole body can heal faster.

I think drinking the aloe is a great idea... also I would drink at least a quart of water 30 minutes before your workout to help with lubricating your joints and helping with flexibility.

I would concentrate on bench press and squat for maximum benefit for your time. They work out a large grouping of muscles and give much more benefit than isolated muscle exercises. Remember form and consistency is more important than weight. Form first weight second.

I wish you the best brother.

Answer (score 0):

When body is making more mass & skin doesn't get enough time, you will get stretch marks.
         and it all depends on your daily intake, so try to gain good muscle mass, as they say it takes 6 months to build a Rolls Royce and 10 hours for a Toyota.
         as if now what you can do is get an alovera Gel or if you have Alovera plant use its gel.
         use it twice.(you can also mix it with coconut oil.)
         1. Before Going to Bed.
         2. Before Taking Bath.
         You can also buy the liquid alovera to drink daily empty stomach in morning.

```
     it helped me, hope it helps you.
```

Comment: What does "skin doesn't get enough time", and, "it all depends on you daily intake" mean?

Comment: I appreciate your help, I definitely gotta try that out.

Comment: -1 for unsubstantiated bro-science. It saddens me greatly that this was selected as an accepted answer.